# Rcpp: how to delete temp files generated by sourceCpp?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

I have a few datasets that look like this

```
mdf <- data.table(matrix(rexp(100 * 100, rate = 0.1), ncol = 100))
mwt <- data.table(V1 = rexp(100, rate = 10))
start <- 2
```

I run a fairly simple code as following

```
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(Rcpp)

rcpp_code <- "// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat rcpp_ApplyTimeShifting(arma::mat data, arma::mat weights, int start) {
  const int len = weights.size();
 
  for (int i = start; i < len; i++) {
    data.row(i) = data.row(i - 1) * (1 - weights.row(i)(0)) + data.row(i) * weights.row(i)(0);
  }
  return data;
}
"

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = rcpp_code)

temp <-rcpp_ApplyTimeShifting( as.matrix(mdf),  as.matrix(mwt), start)
```

and every time i run this, a compiler file is generated in
C:\Users*username*\AppData\Local\Temp

how can i:

- Either automatically delete the compiler file after the usage of the Rcpp function is over     *OR*
- Let the Rcpp function use always the same compiler (so that it does no build a new compiler file every time i run it)

thanks

Comment: The files are in the standard temporary directory of your R session which (by default) gets cleaned when you exit this R session. If you don't want the temporary files, you could compile only once (also ideally as a package) and install.

Comment: @Dirk thanks dirk. Do you have any link to suggest that guides on how to compile only once (also ideally as a package) and install?

Comment: Sure, see the [A Brief Introduction to Rcpp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-introduction.pdf) vignette for a start, as well as [over 200 question here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brcpp%5D+create+package+is%3Aquestion) on SO.

Comment: @Dik such a valuable comment, thanks!